# Render a button in a block

Tags: forms, blocks, theming

I want to display a button on the homepage. The best solution i've thought about was to render it in a block. The code is the following :

```
  $button['my_tickets'] =array(
    '#type'       => 'link',
    '#title'      => t('My tickets'),
    '#href' => '',
    '#class' => 'btn btn-default',
    '#id' => '',
    '#options' => array(
      'html' => true,
    )
  );
```

And here's the theme :

```
  function My_module_theme() {
    return array(
      'my_module_my_button' => array(
        'variables' => array('vars' => NULL),
        'template' => PATH_TO_TEMPLATE,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Problem** : The link isn't rendered with the classes inside the "a" tag. How can I do that ?

Comment: The best way would depend on how your homepage is set up currently. Do you use panels? Just blocks? Is there any WYSIWYG content on the homepage already? Chances are you should add it using a WYSIWYG or possible use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

Comment: I don't use panels, just block. No wysiwyg content in the homepage for now.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the block through the UI `admin/structure/block/add` and using the WYSIWYG editor to make the link and then style it as a button?

Comment: I have to make it translatable afterwards. Having it constructed trought the UI would prevent me from it.

Comment: Blocks can be translated as well via Block languages module (i18n_block) - part of Internationalization module (https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the classes should be added in the attributes array:

```
 $button['my_tickets'] =array(
    '#type'       => 'link',
    '#title'      => t('My tickets'),
    '#href' => '',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-default')),
    '#id' => '',
    '#options' => array(
      'html' => true,
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code instead

```
$link = array(
  '#theme' => 'link',
  '#text' => 'Click Here',
  '#path' => $path,
  '#options' => array(
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('cool-class'), 'id' => 'cool-id'),
      //REQUIRED:
      'html' => true,
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a slightly complex way of making a button, Why not just add to your **page** or **page-front** template:
    `<a href="your-link-destination" class="btn btn-default">My tickets</a>`

Comment: Because hard-coding links in to a tpl is bad practice.

Comment: No hard-coding allowed in the project ^^

Comment: aha! I see you updated your question with more specifics!